# Image resizing not working (using base64)

Tags: php, string, image, converters

The following code is supposed to output a resized image in a string. Unfortunately it only outputs MQ== so where is my mistake? Help is really appreciated :)

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'tick.png';

// Set a maximum height and width
$width = 200;
$height = 200;

// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

$newImage = imagepng($image_p, null, 100); // got in has to be from 0 to 9
echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($newImage)); // this still does not work°
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compression level can't be 100. Only from 0 to 9.

```
imagepng($image_p, null, from 0 to 9);
```

Base64 encode you can do with:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($image_p, null, 9); // got in has to be from 0 to 9
$stream = ob_get_clean();
echo base64_encode($stream);
```

Comment: echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($newImage)); not working

Answer (score 3):

This is how i do it:

```
      $Temp_Dump = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
      // Get new sizes
      list($width, $height) = getimagesize($Temp_Dump);
      $newwidth = 90;
      $newheight = 90;

      // Load
      $Temp_thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
      //$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($Temp_Dump);

      if($extension == "jpg" OR $extension=='jpeg'){ 
      $source = ImageCreateFromJpeg($Temp_Dump); 
      }elseif ($extension == "gif"){ 
      $source = ImageCreateFromGIF($Temp_Dump); 
      }elseif ($extension == 'png'){
       $source = imageCreateFromPNG($Temp_Dump);
      }

      // Resize
      imagecopyresized($Temp_thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
```